# How to add specific values from 2 JSON objects, to a new JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, function, object

I have extracted the amount of times a country appears in an object (shown at the bottom). My problem is i need the geocode informaition to go along with they country names+amount of times the appear, so i can plot the actual result on the actual country on my map.

So from the object below, the resulting object from the mapToProp function would be

```
Germany:3,
United Kingdom: 1
```

But I need something like below. Because this is the format mapbox seemingly expects geojson objects to be.

```
   {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -77.034084142948,
                    38.909671288923
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "name":'Germany',
                "amount": 3
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -77.034084142948,
                    38.909671288923
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "name":'United Kingdom',
                "amount": 4
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Getting the country names+the amount of time they appear

```
   function mapToProp(data, prop) {
        return data
          .reduce((res, item) => Object
            .assign(res, {
              [item[prop]]: 1 + (res[item[prop]] || 0)
            }), Object.create(null))
        ;
      }
```

The result returned back from the geocoder (this is what country do some specific titles appear in)

```
var data = [
  {
    bbox: [
      5.866003, 47.270461, 15.041428, 55.0845576
    ],
    center: [
      10, 51
    ],
    geometry: {
      coordinates:[
        10, 51
      ],
      type: "Point"
    }
  }, {
    id: "country.10743216036480410",
    place_name: "Germany",
    place_type: ["country"],
    properties: {
      short_code: "de",
      wikidata: "Q183"
    },
    relevance: 1,
    text: "Germany",
    type: "Feature"
  }, {
    bbox: [
      5.866003, 47.270461, 15.041428, 55.0845576
    ],
    center: [
      10, 51
    ],
    geometry: {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates:[
        10, 51
      ]
    },
    id: "country.10743216036480410",
    place_name: "Germany",
    place_type: ["country"],
    properties: {
      short_code: "de",
      wikidata: "Q183"
    },
    relevance: 1,
    text: "Germany",
    type: "Feature"
  }, {
    bbox: [
      5.866003, 47.270461, 15.041428, 55.0845576
    ],
    center: [
      10, 51
    ],
    geometry: {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates:[
        10, 51
      ]
    },
    id: "country.10743216036480410",
    place_name: "Germany",
    place_type: ["country"],
    properties: {
      short_code: "de",
      wikidata: "Q183"
    },
    relevance: 1,
    text: "Germany",
    type: "Feature"
  }, {
    bbox: [
      -8.718659, 49.802665, 1.867399, 60.945453
    ],
    center: [
      -2, 54
    ],
    geometry: {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates:[
        10, 51
      ],
    },
    id: "country.8605848117814600",
    place_name: "United Kingdom",
    place_type: ["country"],
    properties: {
      short_code: "gb",
      wikidata: "Q145"
    },
    relevance: 1,
    text: "United Kingdom",
    type: "Feature"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Based on the update desired result (grouping by `type` then by `place_name`) you could do that 2 ways...

1. **Quick & dirty (more brittle)**

   - since you `data` array only includes objects with the `type` === `Feature`, you could just add that property and return them nested in the `features` array...

```
function groupByProp(data, prop) {
    let objsByPlaceName = data.reduce((res, item) => {
            if (!item[prop]) 
                return res;
            let existing = res[item[prop]],
                amount = existing && existing.amount
                    ? existing.amount + 1
                    : 1,
                newObj = (() => {
                    if (existing && existing.geometry) 
                        return {amount, geometry: existing.geometry};
                    if (item.geometry) 
                        return {amount, geometry: item.geometry};
                    return {amount};
                })();
            return Object.assign(res, {
                [item[prop]]: newObj
            })
        }, {})

    return {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": Object.keys(objsByPlaceName).map(key=> {
             let obj = objsByPlaceName[key];
             return {
                type: "Feature",
                geometry: obj.geometry,
                properties: {
                  name: key,
                  amount: obj.amount
                }
             }
        })
    }
}
```

*There are more efficient way to handle this (N1 vs N^2), but that would require a lot of juggling of property names and manipulating deeply nested values. I'd recommend leaving the initial `groupByProp()` logic and then flattening that data into the desired structure afterwards.*

2. **More flexible**

   - If you're expecting to group elements with different values for `type` then you will have to group by that property first. This actually takes quite a bit of work given the data structures so let me know if you actually want the solution before put it together.

**INITAL ANSWER:**

```
function groupByProp(data, prop) {
  return data
    .reduce((res, item) => {
      if (!item[prop]) return res;
      let existing = res[item[prop]],
          amount = existing && existing.amount ? existing.amount + 1 : 1,
          newObj = (()=> {
            if (existing && existing.geometry) return {amount, geometry: existing.geometry};
            if (item.geometry) return {amount, geometry: item.geometry};
            return {amount};
          })();
      return Object.assign(res, { [item[prop]]: newObj } )
    },{});
}

groupByProp(data, 'place_name')
```

This is likely close to what you're looking for except the first element in the `data` array you provided doesn't have a `place_name` property so if you wont to hanlde that differently you will have to change this line...

`if (!item[prop]) return res;`

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you have any questions about what I implemented.

Comment: Yea actually, I've updated my OP at the bottom is the the format the particular geo placer i'm using expects. Whilst the code runs without any errors, I can't plot any points since it needs the 'Type': So i thought moving the name and amount into a properties key which the geo placer accepts for additional items.

Comment: The example I provided will actually leave everything inside the `geometry` property so it will retain the `type` property nested inside. Is the result you're looking for whats below *"Attempt so far"* or whats below *"But I need something like"*? Please update the assertion under *"But I need something like"* to be **exactly** what you're looking for and we can make that happen.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I'm going through your code and learning a lot which is even better than solving the particular issue. I've gone ahead and updated my OP

Comment: I think you've got the right mentality. I see what you're trying to accomplish now *(I think)*... you want to group by `type:`, then within that by `place_name:`?

Comment: yea basically, it needs to match the format. So each one will be of the same type, but their country name, geometry and amount will be different

Comment: Oops solution I just provided isn't correct... give me a minute